# The martingale $M_t,\mathcal{F}_t$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t +}$

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes

Let $M_t$ be a right continuous martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. Can we say that $M_t$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$?

**Attempt:** We know that $\mathcal{F}_{t+} = \cap_{s >t} \mathcal{F}_{s}$ therefore $\mathcal{F}_{t+} \subset \mathcal{F}_{t + \delta}$ for every $\delta > 0$. Therefore

$$ \Bbb{E}\big[\big(\Bbb{E}\big[M_t\mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}\big] - M_s\big)^2\big]  \leq \Bbb{E}\big[\Bbb{E}\big[ \big (M_t - M_s\big)^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}\big]\big] = \Bbb{E}\big[\lim_{\delta \to 0}\Bbb{E}\big[ \big (M_{s + \delta} - M_s\big)^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}\big]\big] $$

Now using Doob's inequality er obtain that $$\Bbb{E}\big[ \sup_{s \leq t \leq s+1} (M_{s + \delta} - M_s\big)^2\big] \leq C \Bbb{E}\big[ (M_{s + 1}\big)^2\big]$$

Therefore, the bounded convergence theorem plus the right continuity gives us that

$$ \Bbb{E}\big[\big(\Bbb{E}\big[M_t\mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}\big] - M_s\big)^2\big]  \leq \Bbb{E}\big[\lim_{\delta \to 0}\Bbb{E}\big[ \big (M_{s + \delta} - M_s\big)^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}\big]\big]  = 0$$

Is the above correct? Is there another solution for this problem?

Best

Comment: Your random variables don't need to be square integrable, so you can't prove it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t>s$, $A\in \mathcal{F}_{s+}$, and $\delta>0$, where $s+\delta <t$, from the right continuity,
\begin{align*}
\int_A M_t\, dP &= \int_A E(M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{s+\delta})\,dP\\
&=\int_A M_{s+\delta} \, dP\\
&\rightarrow\int_A M_s \, dP.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E(M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}) = M_s.
\end{align*}

Comment: The passage to the limit here needs to be justified.  One way to do this is to notice that the collection of random variables $\{M_{s+\delta}: 0<\delta<t-s\}$ is uniformly integrable, because each random variable in the collection is a conditional expectation of the $L^1$ random variable $M_t$.

Comment: Thank you @JohnDawkins, I missed that part. Now the proof is complete.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Thanks for your addition.